# Divide overlapping angle areas in such a way that individual, non-overlapping angle areas are created (in R)

Tags: r, loops, angle

I´m working in R:
I have a matrix with given starting and ending angles which define an area.
Now there are areas that overlap with one or more other areas.

For further calculations I need non-overlapping angle areas. The angles should be split until there are no overlapping angle areas anymore.

[The problem looks like this: the pink, blue and green areas should be seperated into five non overlapping areas]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b89GP.png)

My thoughts are:

- looping through the matrix and finding the overlapping areas with the following condition:
  if(ending_angle1 > starting_angle2 & starting_angle1 < ending_angle2){
  As results I get a matrix with the number of areas as rows and columns and a 1 for an overlap and 0 for no overlap.
- then I calculate the value of the overlapping areas and replace the 1 from the previous matrix with this value.
- Now I need to calculate the new starting and ending values - but there is somehow the problem...
  I don´t know how to get to the point, that there are starting and ending angles which cover all the angle areas, but are divided into seperate angle areas each with starting and ending angles.

I think I somehow need to use a while loop and always iterate through the matrix comparing every angle with each other until there are no overlappings anymore.

This is what I came up with in R:

```
baumtabelle_neu <- baumtabelle_neu <- dput(baumtabelle_neu)
structure(list(h = c(10, 15, 15, 20), KM = c(8, 10, 10, 13), 
    Nr_Baum = c(1, 2, 3, 4), alpha01 = c(0, 0, 29.5519238759541, 
    25.9206115365844), alpha02 = c(0, 36.869897645844, 76.7082808323578, 
    38.0901548795826), e = c(0, 6.32455532033676, 5, 9.4339811320566
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))
> structure(
+   list(
+     h = c(10, 15, 15, 20),
+     KM = c(8, 10, 10, 13),
+     Nr_Baum = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
+     alpha01 = c(0, 0, 29.5519238759541,
+                 25.9206115365844),
+     alpha02 = c(0, 36.869897645844, 76.7082808323578,
+                 38.0901548795826),
+     e = c(0, 6.32455532033676, 5, 9.4339811320566)
+   ),
+   class = "data.frame",
+   row.names = c(NA, 4L)
+ )
   h KM Nr_Baum  alpha01  alpha02        e
1 10  8       1  0.00000  0.00000 0.000000
2 15 10       2  0.00000 36.86990 6.324555
3 15 10       3 29.55192 76.70828 5.000000
4 20 13       4 25.92061 38.09015 9.433981
> 
> # That is what I´m trying so far:
> 
> # Matrix for the value of the overlapping areas
> ueberschneidung_wert <- matrix (0, nrow = nrow(baumtabelle_neu), ncol = nrow(baumtabelle_neu))
> colnames(ueberschneidung_wert) <- c(1:nrow(baumtabelle_neu))
> 
> for (i in 1:nrow(baumtabelle_neu)) {
+   for (j in 1:nrow(baumtabelle_neu)) {
+     if (i == j){
+       ueberschneidung_wert [i, j] <- 0
+     } else if (baumtabelle_neu[i, 5] > baumtabelle_neu[j, 4] & baumtabelle_neu[i, 4] < baumtabelle_neu[j, 5]) {
+       ueberschneidung <- min(baumtabelle_neu[i, 5], baumtabelle_neu[j, 5]) - max(baumtabelle_neu[i, 4], baumtabelle_neu[j, 4])
+       ueberschneidung_wert [i, j] <- ueberschneidung
+     } else {
+       ueberschneidung_wert [i, j] <- 0
+     }
+   }
+ }
> 
> # Creating a new matrix for the new starting and ending angles
> alpha_raum_neu <- matrix(ncol=3)
> colnames(alpha_raum_neu) <- c("Nr_Baum", "alpha01_neu", "alpha02_neu")
> alpha_raum_neu <- as.data.frame(alpha_raum_neu)
> 
> for (i in 1:nrow(baumtabelle_neu)){
+   for (j in 1:nrow(baumtabelle_neu)){
+     
+     if ((ueberschneidung_wert[i, j] > 0) & (baumtabelle_neu[i,4] < baumtabelle_neu[j,4])){
+       
+       # Area without overlapping of i
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu) + 1,] = list(0)
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu), 1] <- paste(baumtabelle_neu[i, 3])
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu), 2] <- baumtabelle_neu[i, 4]
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu), 3] <- baumtabelle_neu[i, 5] - ueberschneidung_wert[i,j]
+       
+       # Area without overlapping of j
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu) + 1,] = list(0)
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu), 1] <- paste(baumtabelle_neu[j, 3])
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu), 2] <- baumtabelle_neu[j, 4] + ueberschneidung_wert[i,j]
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu), 3] <- baumtabelle_neu[j, 5] 
+       
+       # Area with overlapping of i and j
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu) + 1,] = list(0)
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu), 1] <- paste(baumtabelle_neu[i, 3], baumtabelle_neu[j, 3])
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu), 2] <- baumtabelle_neu[j, 4]
+       alpha_raum_neu[nrow(alpha_raum_neu), 3] <- baumtabelle_neu[i, 5]
+       
+       # remove rows with the same values
+       remove_rows <- duplicated(alpha_raum_neu[,2:3], fromLast = TRUE) 
+       alpha_raum_neu <- alpha_raum_neu[!remove_rows, ]
+       
+     }
+   }
+ }
> alpha_raum_neu
   Nr_Baum alpha01_neu alpha02_neu
1     <NA>          NA          NA
2        2     0.00000    29.55192
3        3    36.86990    76.70828
4      2 3    29.55192    36.86990
5        2     0.00000    25.92061
6        4    36.86990    38.09015
7      2 4    25.92061    36.86990
8        4    25.92061    29.55192
9        3    38.09015    76.70828
10     4 3    29.55192    38.09015
```

Comment: Can you give a small input data example and corresponding output? If yes, in `dput` format, please.

Comment: Sure, I added it to my description of the problem.